# How to Stop Forced Module Namespace in Elixir Phoenix iex Console?

Tags: namespaces, elixir, phoenix-framework, dotfiles, elixir-iex

When using the `iex` console from my Phoenix application, as follows:

`iex -S mix phx.server`

I cant seem to call `System` functions, such as `System.stop(1)` or `System.halt(1)` as it forces a namespace to the front of the module. An error results as that namespaced module doesnt exist.

`** (UndefinedFunctionError) function MyApp.SomeNamespace.System.stop/1 is undefined or private`

Why does it prepend a namespace to this core module? Why does it produce this error with a module like `System`, but not with modules like `Enum`, `List`, or `Map` ?

Also, if I use `iex` outside of my application source, I can call `System.any_function` as expected.

On further inspection, I can get it to work by calling `Elixir.System.stop/1`. Why do I need to prepend the `System` module with `Elixir.` but I dont need to do that for other Elixir modules?

Within my application code, I call things like `System.backtrace` or `System.get_env` with no aliasing or namespacing required. I also have no modules named `System` in the application (i.e., there is no `Myapp.System` or similar module defined).

Comment: Check if you've got an [.iex.exs](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#module-the-iex-exs-file) file present somewhere.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci indeed, that file exists, and I discovered some code in there that seems to be the culprit for the behavior Ive observed. Thanks! I hadn't known about this sort of config file. Do you think you could formulate an answer from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for an iex.exs file. If there is such a file it is automatically run when iex is run. If you reference namespaces in iex.exs that would explain this behavior.

You can find out more in the docs https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#module-the-iex-exs-file

Comment: This indeed was the source of the behavior I observed!